# Pop up mobile menu not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Having issues with the mobile menu for a site. Opening and closing animation of the background is no worries, gets the information up there, whenever I am testing and click on one of the links it just closes the animation and nothing happens. Also cant get the close animation of the text to work properly.

I have the codepen of just the menu attached below.

```
  <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="turf-home.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="turf-about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="turf-contact-us.html">Get In Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="golf" href="golf-home.html">Home</a></li>
    </div>

    <div class="burger">
    <div class="x"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="z"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-circle">
    </div>

div.burger {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 25;
}
/* Circle Border */
.menu-circle {
  z-index: 20;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 2px white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 11px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: #129d49;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 15px 18px -4px #1b1b1b;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 15px 18px -4px #1b1b1b;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0px 15px 18px -4px #1b1b1b;
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 15px 18px -4px #1b1b1b;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 18px -4px #1b1b1b;
}
/* Individual Bars */
div.x, div.y, div.z {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}
/* Individual Sizing and Position */
div.x, div.y, div.z {
  height: 8px;
  width: 42px;
}
div.x {
  bottom: -57px;
}
div.y {
  bottom: -24px;
}
div.z {
  bottom: 10px;
}
/* Part of JS to Close menu */
div.colapse {
  top: 20px;
  background: #4a89dc;
  -webkit-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
  transition: all 70ms ease-out;
}
/* Part of JS menu animations */
div.rotate30 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  transition: all 50ms ease-out;
}
/* Part of JS menu animations */
div.rotate150 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  transition: all 50ms ease-out;
}
/* Part of JS menu animations */
div.rotate45 {
  bottom: -23px;
  left: -9px;
  width: 60px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
/* Part of JS menu animations */
div.rotate135 {
  bottom: -24px;
  left: -10px;
  width: 60px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
/* Pop-up menu background */
div.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 11px;
  left: 10px;
  background: #129d49;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition-delay: 800ms;
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Part of JS menu Pop-up animations */
div.circle.expand {
  width: 1040px;
  height: 1250px;
  bottom: -860px;
  left: -565px;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
/* Enclosing div of whole menu */
.menu-forward {
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
div.menu {
  height: 242px;
  width: 450px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 88px;
  left: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* Menu + Contents */
div.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition: all all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
/* Menu Content Text */
div.menu ul li a {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -18px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition-delay: 40ms;
  z-index: 101;
}
div.menu li.animate {
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  z-index: 100;
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 134px;
  width: 180px;
  transition-delay: 0.0s;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 193px;
  width: 180px;
  transition-delay: 0.01s;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(3) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 76px;
  width: 280px;
  transition-delay: 0.02s;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(4) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17px;
  width: 280px;
  transition-delay: 0.03s;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

if ("ontouchstart" in window) {
  var click = "touchstart";
} else {
  var click = "click";
}

$("div.burger").on(click, function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
    openMenu();
  } else {
    closeMenu();
  }
});

$("div.menu ul li a").on(click, function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  closeMenu();
});

function openMenu() {
  $("div.circle").addClass("expand");

  $("div.burger").addClass("open");
  $("div.x, div.y, div.z").addClass("collapse");
  $(".menu li").addClass("animate");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div.y").hide();
    $("div.x").addClass("rotate30");
    $("div.z").addClass("rotate150");
  }, 70);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div.x").addClass("rotate45");
    $("div.z").addClass("rotate135");
  }, 120);
  $("div.menu").addClass("menu-forward");
}

function closeMenu() {
  $("div.burger").removeClass("open");
  $("div.x").removeClass("rotate45").addClass("rotate30");
  $("div.z").removeClass("rotate135").addClass("rotate150");
  $("div.circle").removeClass("expand");
  $(".menu li").removeClass("animate");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div.x").removeClass("rotate30");
    $("div.z").removeClass("rotate150");
  }, 50);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div.y").show();
    $("div.x, div.y, div.z").removeClass("collapse");
  }, 70);
  $("div.menu").removeClass("menu-forward");
}
```

Comment: This question might end up being closed because it doesn't meet SO guidelines. Here's their guidance, which might help you improve it: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

- A small sample of code showing what you've tried might improve the question and increase your chance of a better answer.

Comment: Thanks Joe, struggling with how to add the code into the post and now its giving me a headache. haha

Comment: just paste it in and make sure it has at least 4 spaces on the left. Also, keeping the formatting will make it easier to read.

Comment: @JoeMayo I think i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put it in this form so others can see. Well your links aren't working because you have

```
$("div.menu ul li a").on(click, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    closeMenu();
});
```

Which is preventing the click action to go to a new page. What is supposed to happen when you click the links?

**Edit:**
I changed it so that if you want the menu to close and then go to the link, it does that now.

```js
if ("ontouchstart" in window) {
  var click = "touchstart";
} else {
  var click = "click";
}

$("div.burger").on(click, function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
    openMenu();
  } else {
    closeMenu();
  }
});

$("div.menu ul li a").on(click, function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  closeMenu();
  setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
}, 2000);
});

function openMenu() {
  $("div.circle").addClass("expand");

  $("div.burger").addClass("open");
  $("div.x, div.y, div.z").addClass("collapse");
  $(".menu li").addClass("animate");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div.y").hide();
    $("div.x").addClass("rotate30");
    $("div.z").addClass("rotate150");
  }, 70);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div.x").addClass("rotate45");
    $("div.z").addClass("rotate135");
  }, 120);
  $("div.menu").addClass("menu-forward");
}

function closeMenu() {
  $("div.burger").removeClass("open");
  $("div.x").removeClass("rotate45").addClass("rotate30");
  $("div.z").removeClass("rotate135").addClass("rotate150");
  $("div.circle").removeClass("expand");
  $(".menu li").removeClass("animate");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div.x").removeClass("rotate30");
    $("div.z").removeClass("rotate150");
  }, 50);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("div.y").show();
    $("div.x, div.y, div.z").removeClass("collapse");
  }, 70);
  $("div.menu").removeClass("menu-forward");
}
```

```css
div.burger {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 25;
}
/* Circle Border */
.menu-circle {
  z-index: 20;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 2px white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 11px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: #129d49;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 15px 18px -4px #1b1b1b;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 15px 18px -4px #1b1b1b;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0px 15px 18px -4px #1b1b1b;
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 15px 18px -4px #1b1b1b;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 18px -4px #1b1b1b;
}
/* Individual Bars */
div.x, div.y, div.z {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}
/* Individual Sizing and Position */
div.x, div.y, div.z {
  height: 8px;
  width: 42px;
}
div.x {
  bottom: -57px;
}
div.y {
  bottom: -24px;
}
div.z {
  bottom: 10px;
}
/* Part of JS to Close menu */
div.colapse {
  top: 20px;
  background: #4a89dc;
  -webkit-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
  transition: all 70ms ease-out;
}
/* Part of JS menu animations */
div.rotate30 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  transition: all 50ms ease-out;
}
/* Part of JS menu animations */
div.rotate150 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  transition: all 50ms ease-out;
}
/* Part of JS menu animations */
div.rotate45 {
  bottom: -23px;
  left: -9px;
  width: 60px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
/* Part of JS menu animations */
div.rotate135 {
  bottom: -24px;
  left: -10px;
  width: 60px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
/* Pop-up menu background */
div.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 11px;
  left: 10px;
  background: #129d49;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition-delay: 800ms;
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Part of JS menu Pop-up animations */
div.circle.expand {
  width: 1040px;
  height: 1250px;
  bottom: -860px;
  left: -565px;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
/* Enclosing div of whole menu */
.menu-forward {
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
div.menu {
  height: 242px;
  width: 450px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 88px;
  left: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* Menu + Contents */
div.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition: all all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
/* Menu Content Text */
div.menu ul li a {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -18px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition-delay: 40ms;
  z-index: 101;
}
div.menu li.animate {
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  z-index: 100;
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 134px;
  width: 180px;
  transition-delay: 0.0s;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 193px;
  width: 180px;
  transition-delay: 0.01s;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(3) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 76px;
  width: 280px;
  transition-delay: 0.02s;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(4) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17px;
  width: 280px;
  transition-delay: 0.03s;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="turf-home.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="turf-about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="turf-contact-us.html">Get In Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="golf" href="golf-home.html">Home</a></li>
    </div>

    <div class="burger">
    <div class="x"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div class="z"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-circle">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes when you click the link it will take you to the a different page.

So by removing the close menu click function it works. 

Is my understanding right in having this means that whenever a link element is clicked it views it as just close the menu?

Comment: $("div.menu ul li a").on(click, function(e) { e.preventDefault(); closeMenu() });  Are you talking about this code? The e.preventDefault() prevents whatever action that normally takes place when that item is clicked. So that line prevents the link from going to another page. And since it prevents the default, the next item is close menu, so that's what it closes the menu.

Comment: @ThomasWhitaker I changed the function to do the close menu action and then redirect, if that's what your end goal was.